# CPU Fan Speed 0

Tags: dual-boot, cpu, fan, temperature

So, I am using **Asus ROG-GL553VE**. It has **8GB RAM** and runs on **Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows Dual boot**. My issue is, that the fans are making way too much noise even when I am not putting any load on the system. To investigate more about this, I installed a tool called `lm-sensors`. I think I found something weird in the stats

[Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HuuN.png)
[Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8s7V.png)

Here as you can see my `cpu_fan` is running at 0RPM, is this normal? Also I guess if my cpu is not running at all, the sound I am getting from is some system fan, in that case, how can I check it's temp and speed?

How should I solve this issue? The fan always running at full speed is very annoying as it gets very noisy at.

Comment: Seeing you have Windows dual booted, would check on Windows if fan speed is listed.  Speed fan is one windows program.  Some computers/laptops do not have fan sensors to read RPMs.  Would also check if you have newest version of Bios.

Comment: sorry for being late to reply, I will try these steps.